# Inversion of control versus Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

These two concepts seems very similar to me, at least, you can use Dependency Injection just using Reflection and loading the implementation from a config file, so here is my question...

- What is the differece between Dependency Injection and Reflection?
- When i should use Reflection and when Dependency Injection?

Comment: They're very different beasts. You can *implement* a dependency injection framework using reflection, but you don't have to... and likewise there are all kinds of other things you can use reflection for.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the differece between Dependency Injection and Reflection?

Dependency injection is a principle (or practice), while reflection is a tool that allows, amongst other things, to inject a dependency.

They can't actually be compared, as they're completely different concepts. Reflection itself can be used in a variety of ways, unrestricted to this particular context.

> When i should use Reflection and when Dependency Injection?

You can make an injection through reflection, they're not alternatives.